# unset bash function variable with non-standard name

Tags: bash, sh, unset, bash-function

I may have this function in a bash script that gets sourced to the shell

```
function suman{
     echo "using suman function"
}
```

if I call

```
unset suman
```

things seem to work as expected

however if I have this as my function:

```
function suman-inspect {
     echo "using suman-inspect function"
}
```

then if I call

```
unset suman-inspect
```

or

```
unset "suman-inspect"
```

I get this message:

```
bash: unset: `suman-inspect': not a valid identifier
```

How can unset this variable as is?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After some more research, it appears that

```
unset -f "suman-inspect"
```

will work. This is surprising because `unset suman` did work, and did successfully unset the suman function (as far as I could tell).

Comment: +1 Fascinating! The documentation for `unset` says that "If no options are supplied, each *name* refers to a variable; if there is no variable by that name, any function with that name is unset." I'd have assumed that this would work even if the variable is not a valid variable-name, but apparently not!

Comment: Probably what happens is that `unset` *assumes* that its argument (sans `-f`) is an identifier, but if no variable by that name exists, checks to see if you meant to unset a function instead. Only if you explicitly use `-f` does `bash` relax the "argument must be a valid identifier" rule. Quite a few `bash` extensions lack precisely documented descriptions of their semantics; some other examples include process substitution (e.g, where does `>(...)` inherit its standard *output* from?) and function exports (cf. ShellShock).

Comment: Does the hyphen/dash in suman-inspect make it an invalid identifier?

Answer (score 2):

Bash allows functions with names which are not valid identifiers to be created when not in posix mode.

So:

```
set -o posix
function suman-inspect { echo "using suman-inspect function"; }
```

Gives:

```
bash: `suman-inspect': not a valid identifier
```

[ruakh](https://stackoverflow.com/users/978917/ruakh) makes a valid point by quoting `man bash`.  The source code (`builtins/set.def`) has the comment:  *Posix.2 says try variables first, then functions*, but ...

The [POSIX standard](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009696699/utilities/unset.html) says *If neither -f nor -v is specified, name refers to a variable; if a variable by that name does not exist, it is unspecified whether a function by that name, if any, shall be unset.*

So actually the behaviour is that old standby "unspecified*.  If anything, the error is in the bash documentation.  But to be fair, elsewhere in `man bash` it says:

*A  function  definition  may  be deleted  using  the  -f  option  to the unset builtin.*